# Прошу помочь с расстановкой знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Варианты следующие:

«Если я не про салат говорю сейчас, а про, допустим, направление, то нельзя» или
«Если я не про салат говорю сейчас, а про допустим другое направление смысла этого слова, то нельзя».

Какой из них правильный?

Comment: Точка ставится в конце предложения после кавычек, а перед "или" всё предложение не заканчивается, поэтому точка вообще не нужна. "Допустим" и там, и там вводное, поэтому и во втором случае надо обособить.

Comment: Семантика  предложения неясна,  поэтому и стилистика под вопросом. Соответственно,  сложно говорить о какой-либо правильности. Также можно предположить, что вводное слово не должно находиться внутри предложного сочетания (а, допустим, про другое)

Comment: Вас пунктуация интересует или вібор из двух вариантов изложения мысли? Если последнее, то "оба хуже".

Answer (score 0):

Слово "допустим" может являться либо глаголом 1-го лица множественного числа будущего времени, либо вводным словом, выражающим связь мыслей в предложении и относящимся к данному моменту времени(несмотря на время его "родителя"). Хотя, опять же, есть некоторые исключения при определении времени.

Для определения роли данного слова разберем определенную часть предложения по составу:

"Если я не про салат говорю (не про салат, а про что? Здесь имеем два однородных дополнения, соединенных противительным союзом "а") сейчас, а про, допустим, (говорю про что?) десерт..."

Видим, что здесь есть тесная связь между членами, а слово "допустим" разрывает её, поэтому является вводным словом.

Ответ: запятая ставится.